# sql like clause with many values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have 4 columns in my table. Now since this is more of a data cleanup task I am not really that particular about the performance. But still I would like to know the possible options.

Look at the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule ADDR WHERE 
addr.src_address_line1 LIKE '%DEP%' 
OR addr.src_address_line2 LIKE '%DEP%'
OR addr.src_address_line3 LIKE '%DEP%'
OR addr.src_address_line4 LIKE '%DEP%';
```

Similar to DEP I have 10 more matches. I need to repeat each match for all the 4 address lines. Is there a better way to do it? I personally hate writing again and again.

**Updated: Below is the answer

```
SELECT *
FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule ADDR
WHERE regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),      'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
```

Comment: Have you looked at Full text searches? [MySQL Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: There's no way to use `IN` and `LIKE` together, and for good reason: at the point where you start to "need" those two operators together, you've reached a point where you should consider other options (such as full text searches, as @SidewaysGravity suggested). Having too many `LIKE` operations in a query will be dramatically slow.

Comment: I know you are right. I have been looking at regexp_like clause. What do you think about it?

Comment: I would definitely use `REGEXP_LIKE()` along with concatenation (not because it will be faster, just to make things more terse): `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(addr.src_address_line1 || addr.src_address_line2 || addr.src_address_line3 || addr.src_address_line4, '(DEP|OTH1|OTH2|OTH3)')`

Comment: @SidewaysGravity, the OP is using Oracle not MySQL.

Comment: @Bytekoder, you can avoid using `UPPER()` by specifying `'i'` (for case-Insensitive) as the third parameter in `REGEXP_LIKE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [regexp_like](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) function

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a stored procedure, with the 'DEP' part entered as a parameter.
Then just concatenate results from all stored-proc calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW VW_dsopi_person_addr_rule
AS
  SELECT Primary_key
       , src_address_line1 AS src_address_line
    FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule
   UNION
  SELECT Primary_key
       , src_address_line2
    FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule
   UNION
  SELECT Primary_key
       , src_address_line3
    FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule
  SELECT Primary_key
       , src_address_line4
    FROM dsopi_person_addr_rule

DELETE FROM VW_dsopi_person_addr_rule
  WHERE Primary_key in (SELECT Primary_key
                          FROM VW_dsopi_person_addr_rule
                         WHERE src_address_line like '%DEP%)

DELETE D1 FROM VW_dsopi_person_addr_rule D1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM VW_dsopi_person_addr_rule V1
                 WHERE V1.Primary_key_value1 = D1.Primary_key_value1
                   AND V1.Primary_key_value2 = D1.Primary_key_value2
                   AND V1.src_address_line like '%DEP%')
```

Comment: I like your answer but don't you think its a little over work for a clean up task?